# How to enlarge a Asymptote picture (like TikZ spy package)?

Tags: asymptote

My code:

```
// asy -f png <name_of_file>.asy
settings.render=15;
defaultpen(fontsize(6pt));
size(100);

path a,a1;
a=(0,0)--2*dir(45);
a1=shift(0,-2)*a;


draw(rotate(45)*scale(0.7)*"PenMargin(is also EndPenMargin)", g=a1,Arrows(FillDraw(red,blue)),Bars,PenMargin);
draw(circle(relpoint(a1,1),0.05)); 
arrow(relpoint(a1,1)+0.05*dir(45),dir(45/2),NoMargin);

picture pic;
size(pic,50,false);
draw(pic,rotate(45)*scale(0.7)*"PenMargin(is also EndPenMargin)", g=a1,Arrows(FillDraw(red,blue)),Bars,PenMargin);
clip(pic,circle(relpoint(a1,1),0.05));
draw(pic,circle(relpoint(a1,1),0.05));
add(shift(-.3,0)*pic);
shipout(bbox(Fill(white)));
```

Output

[image]

I want to it looks like

[image]

Comment: There's code for something like that here: https://github.com/charlesstaats/asymptote_tutorial/blob/0aa09a62abd5778d69fa0267c71e82188e2d5715/asymptote_tutorial.tex#L2510

Comment: @CharlesStaats That is a good starting point. Thanks, I will have a look at it.